# Removing the shadow on a UIButton while it's being held

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` which highlighted state involves removing the shadow. What I tried doing is putting a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` onto the button:

```
let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.removeShadow))
gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
gesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
gesture.delaysTouchesBegan = false
gesture.delaysTouchesEnded = false
gesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.01
self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

Then in my action, I'm using the states to hide and show the shadow:

```
 @objc func removeShadow(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .recognized {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
        })
    } else if gesture.state == .ended {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.15
        })
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to trigger anything. The shadow keeps living under the button. Am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you adding a gesture recognizer to a UIButton object in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

Your gesture recognizer is being overridden by the selector of the button. It'd be better in your scenario to override the button and hide its shadow when it's selected.

```
class ShadowButton: UIButton {
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
                self.layer.shadowOpacity = self.isHighlighted ? 0 : 0.15
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, good suggestion though. The button's selective is never toggled it seems like... weird.

Comment: @WesleyPeeters I edited my answer, it should work with `isHighlighted`.